# Customise the default "Follow-up" list in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Does anyone know whether it's possible to customise the default options on the "Follow up" list in Outlook 2007? It comes with Today, Tomorrow, This Week, Next week, No date and custom. I get loads of emails that don't need to be followed up that quickly. Would like "Next two weeks" and "Next month".

Or is it time to dust down my Outlook VBA skills?

Thanks, Rob.